# In C# how can I access a variable outside of the scope where it was set?

Tags: c#, variables, scope

I have tried creating a function which opens a configuration file, reads a particular line to get a stored value and then return that value to the calling sub. Because I'm trying to return it outside of the while loop I am getting a compile error. How would I go about getting a stored value and setting it as a variable that I can use elsewhere in my namespace?

```
public class Functions
{
    public static string GetODVPath()
    {
        //Read stored path of ODV.accdb file
        string fileName = @"C:\Users\" + Environment.UserName + @"\ODV.conf";

        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(fileName))
        {
            string line;
            while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                //if line length isnt 0 and line starts with [odv] set value of path
                string odvPath = (line.Length != 0 && line.StartsWith("[ODV]")) ? line.Substring(4) : "";
                
            }
            return odvPath();
        }
        

    }
}
```

Comment: You return the value of the string from the function. Right now, you are attempting to return the result of calling a string variable as a function, which is likely throwing an exception. Leave off the parentheses, declare the string `odvPath` outside the `while` with a sensible default value, and you'll be good.

Comment: Are you asking for something like this? `string line; string odvPath = string.Empty; while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null) { odvPath = (line.Length != 0 && line.StartsWith("[ODV]")) ? line.Substring(4) : ""; } return odvPath;` (in this case the ternary operator is useless and a simple if is enough, but do you want to break on the first found, or take the last?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isn't it what you need?

```
class YourApp
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string odvPath = Functions.GetODVPath();
        // Do whatever you wish with that
    }
} 

public class Functions
{
    public static string GetODVPath()
    {
        string fileName = @"C:\Users\" + Environment.UserName + @"\ODV.conf";
        
        // If you not sure that file always will be at its place
        if (!File.Exists(fileName))
        {
            return string.Empty;
        }

        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(fileName))
        {
            string line;

            while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
            {            
                if (line.StartsWith("[ODV]")))
                {  
                   return line.Substring(4);
                }            
            }
        }

        return string.Empty;       
    }
}
```

This way method returns a value, if it was found, or empty string, if not.
In fact that `Functions` class and its method `GetODVPath` is `public` - they are available for call anywhere in namespace.

EDITED: `line.Length` check may be removed because if `line.StartsWith("[ODV]")` is `true` - it anyway will have at least 4 chars length and next Substring(4) call will just replace "[ODV]" part of found line.
Also added a File.Exists check, which is useful if there is an opportunity that file doesn't exists.

Also, imho, it may be simplified with `System.Linq` `Where` extension method:

```
public static string GetODVPath()
{ 
    // Changed with SpecialFolder enum 
    string fileName = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.UserProfile) + @"\ODV.conf";
        
    // If you not sure that file always will be at its place
    if (!File.Exists(fileName)) // Don't forget to add System.IO reference
    {
        return string.Empty;
    }
    
    // Where filtration looks much simple
    string result = File.ReadAllLines(fileName).Where(line => line.StartsWith("[ODV]")).FirstOrDefault();
    
    // Here is where ternar is in right place :)
    return string.IsNullOrEmpty(result) ? string.Empty : result.Substring(4);
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I can see part of my problem is that I was trying to create the function in the wrong place. I tried creating a new Class file and placing it there. Then I tried putting it just inside the code block of my namespace. I'm fairly new to C# and have been using VBA so I appreciate you're guideance.

Comment: One follow up, in the conf file I have the user entering a fully qualified network path for an Access database file. The code returns:   "]\\\\fileServerName\\subFolder\\anotherSubFolder\\yetAnotherSubFolder\\odv.accdb" how could I prevent it from including "]\\"?

Comment: Change StartIndex value in Substring call from 4 to 5.
`string str = "[ODV]FooBar";`
`string str1 = str.Substring(4);`
`string str2 = str.Substring(5);`

`str1` will result with `"]FooBar"`, `str2` will result with `"FooBar"`.
Refer to [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.substring?view=net-5.0) for more information.
Char at specified in Substring index will be first char in new string.

Also you shouldn't remove `"]\\"`, only bracket `"]"`, because network paths start with double backslashes \\Dir1\Dir2 which is \\\\Dir1\\Dir2\\ inside of your code.

Answer (score -1):

If you want use this variable in external class:

```
class YourApp
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var generateOdvPath = new Functions();
        generateOdvPath.GetODVPath();
        string odvPath = generateOdvPath.GeneralOdvPath;
    }
} 

public class Functions
{
    public string GeneralOdvPath { get; set; }
    public void GetODVPath()
    {
        //Read stored path of ODV.accdb file
        string fileName = @"C:\Users\" + Environment.UserName + @"\ODV.conf";

        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(fileName))
        {
            string line;
            while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                //if line length isnt 0 and line starts with [odv] set value of path
                string odvPath = (line.Length != 0 && line.StartsWith("[ODV]")) ? line.Substring(4) : "";
            }
        }
        GeneralOdvPath = odvPath;
    }
}
```

Remove a static word and declare a propiety for your path.